# In Apache 2.x, how to limit access to files by MIME type?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mime

I have a fairly simple question but I can't find the right answer using Google or going through the Apache manual.

Let's say I have a file system directory on my web server that contains files of different type. Using on virtual host, I want to allow full access to all files in that directory. Using a separate virtual host that uses the same directory as content root, I want to restrict access to files of certain MIME types (equal to looking at the file extension per regexp maybe?).

How do I implement this in Apache in the second virtual host?

Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Tobias

Answer (score 0):

The ["Files" directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#files) looks promising to me, according to [this post](http://www.ducea.com/2006/07/21/apache-tips-tricks-deny-access-to-certain-file-types/), inside your vhost or directory config you can specify (or scope) file names via regex and when deny access as usual:

```
<Files ~ "\.inc$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

The "FilesMatch" directive is preferred when applying a regex.